# Microsoft Office 2016 reporting not enough memory

Tags: macos, ms-office, memory, software, word-processor

I have 2016 MBP with Touch Bar, Radeon Pro 460, macOS Sierra 10.12.2 installed. Word 2016 is sluggish and keeps reporting that I either won't be able to undo an action or am not able to perform it at all because I do not have enough memory.

I have 16 gigabytes of RAM, Word consumes about 350MB while working on 40-page document. It doesn't matter if I have 1 or 10 gigs free memory, the message appears regardless of that. I have over 800GBs free on my SSD. Is that another bug in Microsoft's product?

Comment: Nothing looking heavy in Activity Monitor? What's your system uptime? Type `uptime` in Terminal. If it's more than a week, reboot.

Comment: Nothing particularly heavy. Is that normal that kernel_task consumes >1GB for the most of time? I make reboots quite often, at least once per 2 days. I also checked the SDD using Disk Utility, everything looks fine.

Now it came to my mind that the issue may be caused by keeping the docx file in a git repository. Knowing that's not a great practice, I still feel it's more reliable than cloud drive. I use SourceTree, which checks file status periodically and maybe it locks the docx file. Do you think it may make Word "think" that there's not enough space on the hard drive?

Comment: I'm no expert on MS Office, sorry, very rarely use it, but I've heard before of its awkwardness with remote files. my kernel_task is currently sitting at 3.5GB, though I suspect that's because it includes a 2GB RAM disk I currently have mounted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem disappeared when I turned off SourceTree, which was locking files during periodic refresh. I also noticed that Office for Mac has issues with synchronization while working on files that were opened from OneDrive. So if you're having a similar memory problem, make sure that while you work on the document no other program accesses it.

It seems that Microsoft's products just don't handle file access denial well and I'd consider this behavior a bug.